# Why I can't install django in my virtual enviroment?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Well, basically i'm trying to install django through this code:

```
pipenv install django
```

and the result is:[[image]]

then I have an `ERROR: Couldn't install package:...` thousand of things I can't even show here

I tried to download the new python version and the new django version but keeps asking for python >=3.7 and I can't understand why

I have no idea about what to do because as I stopped backend to study datascience I let django and python on the corner and now I don't even know what happened. I tried to download python 3.12 and Django 5.0 but didn't work

MAYBE as I just deleted some folders from my computer related to django as I wasn't working with it there can be something faulting. When I uninstall django and install again, there is some requirements already installed on my computer and it can be the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check to know that virtualenv is installed (which is what I use for my project). By downloading it using pip install virtualenv, if it has been installed on your machine it will tell you requirement already satisfied.

If not, kindly follow this step:

```py
1. pip install virtualenv
2. virtualenv env (creates the environment folder for your project)
3. If you are on windows, run this command on your CMD or vscode terminal :
env\scripts\activate 

4. If you are on Mac, then run this command instead; env/bin/activate, 

Then it will automatically make the new env you created display at the left hand-side. 
5. Now, install django using pip, and install requirements.txt using pip too.

6. You can now start the project, using this command;
django-admin startproject `myproject` .

Then you can create you Django app modules with :
python manage.py startup `myapp`

And then run the server, and don't forget to freeze the requirements.txt you created via running this command on your terminal below:
pip freeze > requirements.txt

That's it.

Goodluck
```

Comment: Man! you're the best. it really solved the problem, and I learned another way to start a django project now (I used to run the command "pipenv install django" and it didn't give me all the env folder it has now)

Comment: Kindly tick it as answered @AdryanTaborda for other folks having the same issue in the future, to be helpful for them.